# UICollectionView - Downloading images and effective reloading of data, like Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking, uicollectionview

I noticed that apps like Intagram uses `UICollectionViews` to display the feed of photos. 
I also noticed that the cells for these photos is somehow placed on screen **before** the actual photos are downloaded completely. Then when a download completes, that photo is nicely displayed in the correct cell.

I would like to copy that functionality, but I do not know how to go about it.

I am currently downloading a large **JSON** object which I transform to an array of **NSDictionaries**.  Each `NSDictionary` contains information about each photo, and among that information, an URL is presented. At this URL, I can find the corresponding image that I need to download and display in my `UICollectionViewCells`

As for now, I iterate this list and initiate a download for each URL I see. When that download is complete, I reload the collectionview using `[self.collectionView reloadData]`. But, as you can imagine, if I have 30 cells that all wants an image, there is a lot of `reloadData` calls.

I am using AFNetworking to handle the download, here is the method, which I call based on the URL I mentioned before:

```
-(void) downloadFeedImages:(NSString *) photoURL imageDescs:(NSDictionary*)imageDescs photoId:(NSString *)photoID{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* foofile = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:photoID];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile]){
        // IF IMAGE IS CACHED
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"photoURL: %@", photoURL);
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURL]];
    AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                              imageProcessingBlock:nil
                                                                                           success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                                                                               // Save Image
                                                                                               NSLog(@"URL-RESPONSE:%@", image);
                                                                                               NSString *myFile = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:photoID];

                                                                                               NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
                                                                                               [imageData writeToFile:myFile  atomically: YES];
                                                                                               [self.collectionView reloadData];
                                                                                           }
                                                                                           failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                                                               NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                                                                           }];
    [[WebAPI sharedInstance] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

**So** basically, I wonder how I can achieve the functionality that Instagram and similar applications has when it comes to displaying a feed with images. 
In addition, I would like to know a good way to initiate a download for each cell, and when that download is finished, update that cell, not redraw the entire view using **[reloadData]**

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The technique you want to implement is called lazy loading. Since you are using `AFNetworking` it will be easier to implement this in your case. Each of your collection view cell needs to have a `UIImageView` to display the image. Use the `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` category and set the correct image URL by calling method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ....

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    // ...
    return cell;
}
```

Placeholder is the image which will be displayed until required image is downloaded. This will simply do the required job for you.

**Note**: By default, URL requests have a cache policy of `NSURLCacheStorageAllowed` and a timeout interval of 30 seconds, and are set not handle cookies. To configure URL requests differently, use `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:`.

Also, for you reference, if you want to implement lazy loading of images yourself, follow this [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html). This is for `UITableView` but same technique can be used for `UICollectionView` as well.

Hope that helps!

Comment: However, when i implement this, the collectionview is quite hacky when scrolling. is this method completely asynchronous ? Any idea how to make the scrolling of my collectionview less hacky? =)

Comment: @Eyeball Yes this is completely asynchronous. Are there any other operations you are performing like FileIO in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`? Any operations that would cause a noticeable pause in the main thread?

Comment: One more thing, you need not reload the collection for every image now. The AFNetworking code takes care of refreshing the image view once the image is downloaded and assigned to it.

Comment: Spot on, I perform fileIO in cellForItemAtIndexPath. Firstly I check for the correct image in cachesdirectory, if it is there I initialise the image with 'initwithcontentsoffile'-method. If it is not there I download it and then save it to disk 'atomically'. I see now that that this is inefficient and can cause disturbances on the main thread, do you have a suggestion how to solve this? Thank you very much

Comment: AFNetworking already does caching of downloaded images, so you need not perform that check and then call `setImageWithURL: placeholderImage:`. Also you need not save the images separately in caches directory.

Comment: What if I need that image in another view? I am trying to have as little internet communication as possible. Also, can I set the timer for the cache you mention? Like set the cache time to 30mins? 1hr?

Comment: You can use the same category function which will first lookup in the AFNetworking cache, if found will use local copy, if not, it will download fresh copy. Your app caches directory will be wiped off if device receives low memory warning, requiring you to re-download and manage the caching. Instead let AFNetworking do it efficiently :)

Comment: Also AFNetworking will handle resource refresh when caching, Ex it will check the Etag for cached image. If image provider changes the image resource at the same url then AFNetworking will download the modified resource and replace for cached URL.

Answer (score 2):

use

`[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];`

instead of

`[self.collectionView reloadData];`

here `indexPath` is the `NSIndexPath` Object for the corresponding `UICollectionViewCell` Object

Answer (score 1):

Use following to load image Async in cell in **cellForItemAtIndexPath** delegate method

```
let url = URL(string: productModel.productImage)

    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        collectionViewCell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    });
```

Implement protocol **"UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching"** in you ViewController as

**class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching {**

Set following delegates to your collection view in storyboard (see the attached image) 
or programmatically

In **ViewController's** *viewDidLoad* method

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.prefetchDataSource = self
```

Comment: No that `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching` works only on iOS 10+