# Show Image Stored in Firebase Storage (Google Cloud) In UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift

Iv been working on a game for 6 months now and have a problem that i cant seem to fix. There are some questions similar but none exactly fitting my situation.

**Summary**

My game has 200 items. Each Item has a Unlocked Image showing the actual Item and an Locked Image just showing it greyed out. I am going to put all 200 Unlocked Images into Firebase Storage and about 15 Locked Images (since each item has about 15 skins, the base is always the same) too.

**Problem**

The `StoreViewController` page is a `UIViewController` with a `CollectionView` embeded inside of it. When creating the `CollectionViewTableCells` There is the `UIImageView` for each cell. Each cell iterates through a Array of Dictionaries like so (normally this Array will have 150 + dictionaries) :

```
let items : [[String:String]] = [

    [
        "type" : "star",
        "model" : "blackOne",
        "available" : "no",
        "rarity" : "normal",
        "totalOwned" : "1",
        "price" : "9,999",
        "u-image" : "blackone-u",
        "l-image" : "star-l"
    ],
    [
        "type" : "star",
        "model" : "blackTwo",
        "available" : "no",
        "rarity" : "normal",
        "totalOwned" : "1",
        "price" : "10,500",
        "u-image" : "blacktwo-u",
        "l-image" : "star-l"
    ],
    [
        "type" : "square",
        "model" : "black-New",
        "available" : "no",
        "rarity" : "normal",
        "totalOwned" : "1",
        "price" : "12,950",
        "u-image" : "blacknew-u",
        "l-image" : "square-l"
    ]
]
```

The `u-image & l-image` holds the name of the appropriate image for that item. Those same images that are uploaded into Firebase Storage.

**Question**

How should I use the `u-image & l-image` to grab the Firebase Storage and display the correct image in each `UICollectionViewCell's UIImage`? I need to grab  ~ 200 images to display each time they user goes to the `StoreViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly consider replacing "u-image" and "l-image" with the public unguessable url (eg "u-image-url") that is automatically generated for your image.  This Url can be downloaded without special code so you can follow steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458934/uicollectionview-downloading-images-and-effective-reloading-of-data-like-inst) to add placeholders and leverage local image caching.
You can get this public url via the firebase console and also programmatically.

Via the console:
[image]

Programmatically:

```
// Get a reference to the storage service, using the default Firebase App
FIRStorage *storage = [FIRStorage storage];
// Create a storage reference from our storage service
FIRStorageReference *storageRef = [storage referenceForURL:@"gs://<your-firebase-storage-bucket>"];
FIRStorageReference *imagesRef = [storageRef child:<uimageString_from_array + '.png'>];
[imagesRef downloadURLWithCompletion:^(NSURL URL, NSError error){
  if (error != nil) {
    // Handle any errors
  } else {
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:URL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
  }
}];
```

I would store this url in your database/array instead of decoding it at runtime because its simpler and you'd have a delay setting the placeholder image.

Comment: Awesome Benjamin! I have another question. There are about 10 different placeholder images depending on the "type" of the item. How would I show the appropriate placeholder for each type of gun? That is the reasoning why I had the "u-image" (unlocked image) and the "l-image" (locked image placeholder)